# scikit-learn: add clf.prediction() to different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I've trained my RandomForestClassifier() and am now looking to add my predictions to my newly imported test DF which I'm calling df_test.

I have added my feature columns to the df_test dataframe, for the clf.predict method to use.

I cannot figure out how to use my clf.predict() method in a way to add a new column to df_test.

On My Training Data:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(df3[features], df['rounded_score'])
pd.crosstab(clf.predict(df3[features]), df3['rounded_score'])
```

Get My Test Data Ready:

```
df_test = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df_test['match_ratio'] = df.apply(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(x['search_term'], x['product_title']), axis=1)
df_test['partial_match_ratio'] = df.apply(lambda x: fuzz.partial_ratio(x['search_term'], x['product_title']), axis=1)
df_test['tsort_match_ratio'] = df.apply(lambda x: fuzz.token_sort_ratio(x['search_term'], x['product_title']), axis=1)
```

I have tried about a dozen iterations of code like the below:

```
df_test['prediction'] = df_test[something].apply(lambda x: clf.predict(x))
```

But the predict method keeps telling me it's looking for a numpy array. So, I tried the following, which works:

```
mat = df_test[['match_ratio', 'partial_match_ratio', 'tsort_match_ratio']].as_matrix()
for x in mat[:10]:
    print clf.predict(x)
```

But I can't figure out how to get this data into my df_test dataframe as a new column. My last consideration is appending the prediction to a regular python list, then somehow munging that into the dataframe...but that seems kinda messy.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `df_test[something]` contains the features, you can append a new column containing the predictions writing

```
df_test['prediction']=clf.predict(df_test[something])
```